# Partition/equivalence classes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $N$ be the set of all subsets of {1,2,3,4}. Let

$S_0 :=\{\varnothing\}$

$S_1 :=\{\{1\},\{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\} \}$

$S_2 :=\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\}, \{1,4\}, \{2,3\}, \{2,4\}, \{3,4\} \}$

$S_3 :=\{\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\}, \{1,3,4\}, \{2,3,4\} \}$

$S_4 :=\{\{1,2,3,4\}\}$

show that $S_0,...,S_4$ are a partition of N and determine all the equivalence classes defined by this partition.

---

So it is clear that is a partition because they are pairwise disjoint and their union is $N$. (right?) but how can I determine the equivalence classes? I have read somewhere that two sets will be related if they have the same number of elements? So the the representative of equivalence classes would be $[S_0],[S_1],[S_2],[S_3],[S_4]$?

Comment: The partition is just the set of equivalence classes. So, $(S_i)_{i\in\{1,2,3,4\}}$ are the equivalence classes.

Comment: $S_0,S_1,..,S_4$ are the equivalence classes themselves since equivalence classes are nothing but partitions of a set under some relation. But according to the notation I have been taught, $[x]$ is used to denote the equivalence class containing $x$, so $S_0=[\emptyset],S_1=[\{1\}]=[\{2\}]=[\{3\}]...$ and so on. $[S_i]$ does not make sense.

Comment: and you could take $\{\emptyset\}$, $\{1\}$, $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,2,3\}$, and $\{1,2,3,4\}$ as representatives

Comment: @DonThousand: thank you, but why wouldn't zero be included?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: thank you for that addition! so my equivalence classes were correct?

Comment: It will be included, that was a typo.  As for a lay description of the equivalence relation at play here... two subsets are said to be "related" here iff their cardinality is the same, i.e. if they have the same number of elements.  For example, $\{2,3\}$ is related to $\{2,4\}$ since they both have two elements.  Meanwhile $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is only related to itself since it is the only subset with four elements.

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you very much for your detailed explanation.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that every partition defines an equivalence relation and every equivalence relation defines a partition.  There is a one-to-one correspondence between equivalence relations and partitions.  It so happens that some equivalence relations (*like the one here*) have easy to describe relations using everyday language (*like I did in my previous comment*) but there are of course some equivalence relations which do not happen to coincide with any "natural" descriptions, at which point it may be easier to describe using the partition itself.

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you so much, it was always a little problem for me to understand the equivalence classes, now it is clear.